# Autofac: register an instance of type A, after type A is already registered as type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, autofac

I have a `PortalEntities` class whick extends `DbContext`.

I have a `EFGenRepo` class with a private prop `context` of type `PortalEntites`. This `EFGenRepo` class has a constructor:

`public EFGenRepo(PortalEntities entities) { this.context = entities; }`

Now I have a `ClientManager` class which has an instance of the `EFGenRepo` called `repo`. Remember since the `context` prop in `repo` is private I cannot acces it!

---

Now I have this line of code inside one of the methods of `ClientManager`:

`FKEntityList.Add(new PortalEntities().Set<FKEntity>().Find(FKEntity_id));`

And this is where I get an error message:

- *The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.*

The `FKEntityList` is build using a find method of `repo` which itself uses the `context` prop in `EFGenRepo`.

---

I use autofac and registered `PortalEntities` like this, so it can be injected in a controller:
`cb.RegisterType<PortalEntities>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();`

However in my method I use `new PortalEntites()` and it must be registered too somehow with the Type `PortalEntities`. But I can not get it working. I already tried the code below:

`cb.RegisterInstance(new PortalEntities()).AsSelf().SingleInstance();`

Does somebody know how to setup?

Answer (score 1):

In your ClientManager class, you should not create (and even use) PortalEntities class. Move database query logic into your repository, which already has PortalEntities instance.

Comment: I am not sure my architecture is the best pattern. My `ClientManager` class has an instance of `EFGenRepo`. But it can easy extend `EFGenRepo` instead of using an instance. It is my believe repo's only have to have CRUD methods. Nothing more! But my believe might not be the best! You can see the methods of me `GenManager` class: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866315/cannot-loop-through-list-aicollection-of-generic-type-b-where-a-and-b-both-imp) Note that if I extend it, I must mark the context protected instead of private ofcourse. Your opinion is welcome ranquild.

Comment: In general, there is a repository per entity. Repository has 1 method per create/update/delete operation, and multiple methods for quering data. Service layer uses multiple repositories for bussiness logic.